# To pass 2D Dimensional array as an argument?

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I run the below code , with data array as an local variable it was working fine. but, when I declared it as Global variable it was not working. can anybody please help me how to pass 2D dimensional array into the function.

```
<html>
<table>

 <tr>
  <select id="Ultra" name="letters" onchange="myFunction()">
          <option value="0">1</option>
          <option value="1">2</option>
          <option value="2">3</option>
          <option value="3">4</option>
      </select>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td id="demo">
   <script>
            var data = [[0,1],[1,3],[2,6]];
             function myFunction(data[][]) 
             { 

                var x = document.getElementById("Ultra").value;
                for(i=0;i<data.length;++i)
                {
                  if(data[i][0] == x)
                  {
                    var a = data[i][1];
                  }
                  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = a;
                }
              }


   </script>
   </td>
   </tr>

</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to pass in a 2d array to a function. This is about as simple as I can make it. There's no need to define the type (i.e. don't do `data[][]`) when defining the function (I think that's where you were going wrong).

```
// define 2d array
var data = [[0,1],[1,3],[2,6]];

// define function
function myFunction(foobar){
    // ... do something with 2d array "foobar" ...
}

// invoke function, passing in 2d array
myFunction(data);
```

**Example:** Try it out [using a tool like jsbin](http://jsbin.com/turoji/1/edit?html,js,console)!

Comment: I doubt it was ever working "fine". 1) `data[][]` is not a valid function param. 2) `a` is used outside of the `if` scope. 3) The onchange function doesn't pass in any parameters. Once again, try using a tool like jsbin, it actually helps you with errors like this. Hint: There is no need to pass in a `data[][]` param. If you remove the `data[][]` parameter, it will simply reference the global `data` variable. http://jsbin.com/turoji/2/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the variable directly. It will still be a 2D array inside the function:

```
function myFunction(array) {
    // code
}

myFunction([[1,2],[3,4]]);
```